# How do I make an Emacs keybinding to set a variable?

Tags: emacs, lisp

I've got a variable in Emacs called my-var that I'd like to set whenever I press C-v. How do I do that? I tried this:

```
(defun set-my-var (value)
  "set my var"
  (interactive)
  (defvar my-var value
    "a variable of mine")
)

(global-set-key "\C-v" 'set-my-var)
```

But that fails:

```
call-interactively: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (value) "set my var"
(interactive) (defvar my-var value "a variable of mine")), 0
```

Comment: Ok, I'll bite.  Why do you want this?  What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'd like to be able to turn off font-lock mode and "paint" text manually -- say, highlight matching parens in specific colors. In order to do this, I have an existing function which sets the font foreground to a color that comes out of a variable. I need to be able to set that variable, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, defvar doesn't do what you think it does either: it only changes the value IF there was no value before.  Here's a chunk that does what you're looking for, using the CTRL-u argument:

```
(defun set-my-var (value)
  "Revised version by Charlie Martin"
  (interactive "p")
  (setq my-var value))
```

and here's an example, code from the `*scratch*` buffer

```
(defun set-my-var (value)
  "Revised version by Charlie Martin"
  (interactive "p")
  (setq my-var value)) ; do ^J to evaluate the defun form, showing return in the buffer.
set-my-var

(global-set-key "\C-v" 'set-my-var)
set-my-var
 ;Another ^J

;;; Now, what's the value after ^U^V?
my-var
4
;;; Now ^U 8 ^V
my-var
8
;;; now ^U^U^V
my-var
16
```

Answer (score 3):

It's in the argument.  Look over at the text I just posted about `(interactive)`.  When you bind `set-my-var` to a key, it's looking for an argument, but since you used `(interactive)` there's no argument to be had.  What you *wanted* is something like `(interactive "p")` to get the `CTRL-u` argument, or `(interactive "M")` to get a string.

Read the EMACS Lisp manual on ["Using Interactive."](http://www.tac.nyc.ny.us/manuals/elisp/elisp_230.html)

Comment: Thanks, that allows me to set the variable once. But after it's set once, i can't use C-v to change it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other hints:

- CTRL-v is a standard binding and
  pretty heavily used (`scroll-up`). 
  You'd be better off finding
  something that's not otherwise used.
  Canonically, those would be added to
  the `CTRL-c` keymap.
- Don't get in the habit of treating
  parens as if they were C braces. 
  It's better (more customary) LISP
  style for the rest of us who might
  read your code to just close all the
  parens at the end.

Comment: The code's just an example; the real-life problem is more complex and is bound to C-X P